# Increasing of Bow Tie Antenna Bandwidth

Tags: antenna, simulation, pcb-antenna

I designed different types of bowtie antenna in CST. But this type of antenna results s11 is not good. I want to increase of antenna bandwidth. I'm trying to get better bandwidth by changing antenna sizes. What can I do for it?

Some papers of wideband antenna:

- Design of Bow Tie Antenna in CST Studio Suite Below 2GHz for Ground Penetrating Radar Applications
- Design of Ultra Wide-Band Bowtie Antenna for GPR Applications

Features:

- FR4 substrate
- frequency range: 100-700 MHz (bandwidth range)

Changed parameters:

- feed trace dimension
- substrate dimensions

[image: type1]
[image: type1 results]

[image: type2]
[image: type2 results]

[image: type3]
[image: type3 results]

Comment: these don't look bad at all! So, you can play on all the parameters of your geometry. For example, you can make the taper on your first antenna steeper, or its ends wider, or both.

Comment: Make it thicker in the Z-dimension. I don't know if you can simulate this in CST, but I'd try having copper on both sides of the substrate for the antenna elements (not the feedline). Stitch the layers together with vias all around the edges.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I change the parameters of the antennas, but it does not get better. I use Antenna Magus, but I don't get good results there either.

Comment: You are going to hit the limits on what physics will allow. You can't get arbitrary bandwidth from any geometry. What bandwidth are you *trying* to achieve?

Comment: Try to increase the substrate height (separation between the antenna patch and ground plane). Or perhaps try a different substrate

Comment: @Jason hi,  I try to achieve at least 200-600 MHz bandwidth. I saw some papers at this bandwidth of course different frequency range. I shared this above.

Comment: @DELTA12 hi, I dont use ground plane at the bottom. Can I use it for better results? And I also want to produce this so there are some restrictions.

Comment: @AhmetEnesYILDIRIM can you reference the papers? The physics of bandwidth is bound by *relative* bandwidth. 200-600 MHz is simple to achieve if your center frequency is 1 GHz but very challenging with your center frequency.

Comment: @Jason I added the article above. I can reduce the frequency by increasing the antenna parameters. I think I can increase the bandwidth this way.